# Jest is throwing SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' while using azure-devops-ui\Page component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

**Jest is throwing SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' while using azure-devops-ui\Page component**

I have used ts-jest for transformation

```
    D:\Enablement\steam-azdo-testconfig-utility\src\node_modules\azure-devops-ui\Page.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from ".data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJmaWxlIjoiRDpcXEVuYWJsZW1lbnRcXHN0ZWFtLWF6ZG8tdGVzdGNvbmZpZy11dGlsaXR5XFxzcmNcXG5vZGVfbW9kdWxlc1xcYXp1cmUtZGV2b3BzLXVpXFxQYWdlLmpzIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyJEOlxcRW5hYmxlbWVudFxcc3RlYW0tYXpkby10ZXN0Y29uZmlnLXV0aWxpdHlcXHNyY1xcbm9kZV9tb2R1bGVzXFxhenVyZS1kZXZvcHMtdWlcXFBhZ2UuanMiXX0=
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      2 | import * as React from "react";
      3 | import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
    > 4 | import { Page } from "azure-devops-ui/Page";
        | ^
      5 | import { showRootComponent } from "../Common";
      6 | import "../Styles.scss";
      7 | import "./iconFont.css";

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hub/hub.tsx:4:1)
```

**The versions used
Node: 18.1.0
NPM: 8.12.2**

Package.json details

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "16.8.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.1",
    "azure-devops-extension-api": "^1.158.0",
    "azure-devops-extension-sdk": "^2.0.11",
    "azure-devops-ui": "^2.167.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "react": "16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "16.8.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-select": "^5.2.1",
    "react-st-modal": "^1.1.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.17.0",
    "base64-inline-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.8.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "tfx-cli": "^0.12.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.6.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.5",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
```

**Jest configuration in package.json**

```
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx|jsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(react-native|azure-devops-ui|azure-devops-extension-sdk|react-st-modal)/)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "preset": "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts",
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "lcov",
      "cobertura"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.test.json"
      }
    }
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "reports",
    "reportFile": "test-report.xml",
    "indent": 4
  }
```

**tsconfig.test.json configuartion**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "charset": "utf8",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [  
      "es6",
      "dom"   
    ],
    "types": [
      "react",
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I have tried various options in transformIgnorePatterns and could not succeeded the test

Comment: If you've asked this question anywhere else and get an answer, please post it here.  I'm having the same problem.